# jQuery .on data or event handler?

Tags: jquery

```
//generate toolbar
var $toolbar = $(".toolbar");
$.each(tools, function (i, tool) {
    $("<img>", tool).appendTo($toolbar);
});
var $tools = $toolbar.find("img");

//define drag and drop handlers
$toolbar.on("dragstart", "img", onDrag);
$(".canvas").on({
    dragenter: false,
    dragover: false,
    drop: onDrop
});

//handle commencement of drag
function onDrag(e) {
    $o = $(this).clone();
    var o = e.originalEvent;
    o.effectAllowed = "copy";
    os = { X: o.offsetX, Y: o.offsetY };
}
```

The jQuery documentation says the third parameter for `.on()` is data and the fourth parameter to `.on()` is an event handler if the fourth parameter exists. In this case `onDrag` is the third parameter so it would have to be considered data? It looks very much like an event handler which should be declared as the fourth parameter not the third. Could I get some explanation here?

Comment: Since onDrag is a function, it would be used as the callback. In the api, optional parameters are wrapped in [] meaning they can be omitted.

Comment: jQuery figures out which parameters you've omitted by looking at the types. So if parameter 3 is an object, it's data; if it's a function, it's the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters with square brackets are optional, so a `handler` could be the second parameter if you omit the `selector` and `data` parameters.  It's smart enough to recognize if the last parameter given is a function or function reference, and will use that as the handler.

Comment: Thank you for posting. That's a very good one about the square brackets.